# Extracting video frames from a live video for real time facial landmark analysis in android

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

I am building a real-time facial landmark detection app using android's ML Kit. Currently, I can capture the video using android camerax library. To enable real-time facial landmark detection for the captured video, I need to extract the video frames and pass the frames to the ML Kit Facial Landmark detection function which will process and detect the landmarks present in the video.

I have attached the code snippet below. Could someone please help me out to extract the video frames? If there is any other approach please do let me know.

Thank you.

```
 btnVideo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(mCameraView.isRecording()){return;}

        SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);
        File file = new File(getBatchDirectoryName(), mDateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".mp4");

        mCameraView.setCaptureMode(CameraView.CaptureMode.VIDEO);

        InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, rotationDegree);

        FaceDetectorOptions highAccuracyOpts =
                new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                        .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE)
                        .setLandmarkMode(FaceDetectorOptions.LANDMARK_MODE_ALL)
                        .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                        .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_ALL)
                        .build();

        FaceDetector detector = FaceDetection.getClient(highAccuracyOpts);

        Task<List<Face>> result =
                detector.process(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(
                                new OnSuccessListener<List<Face>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(List<Face> faces) {
                                        for (Face face : faces) {
                                            Rect bounds = face.getBoundingBox();
                                            float rotY = face.getHeadEulerAngleY();
                                            float rotZ = face.getHeadEulerAngleZ();

                                            FaceLandmark leftEar = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR);
                                            if (leftEar != null) {
                                                PointF leftEarPos = leftEar.getPosition();
                                            }
                                            List<PointF> leftEyeContour =
                                                    face.getContour(FaceContour.LEFT_EYE).getPoints();
                                            List<PointF> upperLipBottomContour =
                                                    face.getContour(FaceContour.UPPER_LIP_BOTTOM).getPoints();

                                            if (face.getSmilingProbability() != null) {
                                                float smileProb = face.getSmilingProbability();
                                            }
                                            if (face.getRightEyeOpenProbability() != null) {
                                                float rightEyeOpenProb = face.getRightEyeOpenProbability();
                                            }

                                            if (face.getTrackingId() != null) {
                                                int id = face.getTrackingId();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    }
                                });


        mCameraView.startRecording(file, executor, new VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onVideoSaved(@NonNull OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                galleryAddPic(file, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int videoCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                //Log.i("TAG",message);
                mCameraView.stopRecording();
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: You will need to write your own video frame extractor logic. Check MediaCodec to see if it helps.